# How to implement static interface member to WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have naive bayes classifier C# console application that includes some static methods. And,  I have a web application. Then, I need to convert my console application to WCF service application to use it with my web application. But, the problem is I cannot implement a static interface member. Why? How can I implement static interface member for service application?

IService1.cs:

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void classify(string[] param1);
}
```

Service1.cs:

```
static void classify(string[] param1)
{
    // Some code
}
```

Error:

'NaiveBayesService.NaiveBayesProgram' does not implement interface member 'NaiveBayesService.IService1.classify(string[])'. 'NaiveBayesService.NaiveBayesProgram.classify(string[])' cannot implement an interface member because it is static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Think of what an interface represents: A contract that a given instance of a class contains the methods, properties, indexers, etc, that are defined in the interface.

What would the purpose of implementing an interface on a static class be? You'll never have an instance of a static class.

You can implement your interface on a non-static class within your service and instantiate it as part of starting up the service.

Comment: To elaborate the last sentence, he means do `void classify (string[] param1) { NaiveBayes.classify(pram1); }` in your service implementation.

Comment: So, how can I implement it as a WCF service application? Which way?

Comment: Well, you could refactor the class so that it's not static. Or you could create a non-static "wrapper" class around the static methods, like Scott Chamberlain said. It's hard to say what approach is better without seeing more of your code, but my gut instinct says that the former approach is more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

## Actually, C# does *(or at least, will)* support it.

As of January 2022, the upcoming version of C# and .NET will have full support for so-called `static abstract` members:

```
interface INumber<T>
{
    static abstract T Zero { get; }
}

struct Fraction : INumber<Fraction>
{
    public static Fraction Zero { get; } = new Fraction();

    public long Numerator;
    public ulong Denominator;

    ....
}
```